# Unable to locate flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have added the flutter SDK path to the system environment variable. Rebooted my pc too. but when I enter command flutter(or any other flutter command) on command prompt it showed :

```
'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. I have already tried several time removing and installing flutter SDK again but nothing helped(path- C:\src\flutter\bin)! Initially when I installed flutter SDK it worked fine new project was created and when I debugged the app the process exited(although the app was installed on my device but didn't worked) and as soon as I uninstalled the app and debugged it again it showed me :[vscode snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFJS8.jpg).

when I select "Locate SDK" it shows  [folder dosen't appears to be a SDK folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OytQr.jpg)

Comment: Can't you just click "Locate SDK" and select where Flutter is installed?

Comment: No, then it shows the folder dosen't appears to be a SDK folder. also I have already mentioned above the flutter commands are not recognized on command prompt.

Comment: There's a "Show Log" button on the error in your last screenshot that might help understand why the folder was not detected as a Flutter SDK.